# in which situation different methods in multi-label classifications in scikit learn should be applied

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, multilabel-classification

I have read [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/08/introduction-to-multi-label-classification/) to learn about various method in multi-label classifiers.
I learned that there are 3 techniques to do multi-label classifications:

```
1.Problem Transformation
2.Adapted Algorithm
3.Ensemble approaches
```

In the category of Problem transformations there are more three sub categories:

```
a.Binary Relevance
b.Classifier Chains
c.Label Powerset
```

I know that when we want better result we should apply the ensemble model. 
I would like to know in which situations the other different algorithm we should use.

I know how they differently work, but I do not know when I should use each of them.

And Also there is only two method implemented for `Adapted Algorithm`.
what if I want other methods but implemented in `adapted algorithm` approach?

Please let me know if my statements are not clear.

Thanks,

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking. What do you mean by "consider the whole labels with each other"?

Comment: @VivekKumar thank you so much for following with me. I mean for multi-label classification which approach makes more sense in terms of giving the correct result. In my idea the case in which consider the binary is not realistic.

Comment: Or can you please summarize with these different approach, in which application which one should be applied?

Comment: @VivekKumar Kindly I have updated my question. and I think it now makes more sense :)